# What is the difference between MyClass and MyClass.this.type and how to turn one to another?

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

I have a situation similar to this:

```
trait Abst{
  type T
  def met1(p: T) = p.toString
  def met2(p: T, f: Double=>this.type){
    val v = f(1.0)
    v.met1(p)
  }
}
class MyClass(x: Double) extends Abst{
  case class Param(a:Int)
  type T = Param
  val s = met2(Param(1), (d: Double) => new MyClass(d))
}
```

And it doesn't show errors until I run it, then it says:

> type mismatch;   found: MyClass, required:
>   MyClass.this.type

I tried also a solution with generic type but then I have conflict that this.T differs from v.T.

So I just need to overcome the error message above if possible?

---

**Update**

So, it turns out that `this.type` is the [singleton type](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types) for that single instance. And I proposed in a comment usage of

```
val s = met2(Param(1), (d: Double) => (new MyClass(d)).asInstanceOf[this.type])
```

So just if someone would make a comment about this, I am aware how ugly it is, just interested how unsafe it is?

Also you all proposed to move definition of Param outside the class, which I definitely agree. So its definition will be in the companion object MyClass

Comment: I succeed to run it by adding .asInstanceOf[this.type] to constructor... Ok for now, until I find something more elegant...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want `f` to be of type `Double => Abst`? I ask because although there are ways of referencing the type of the underlying implementation in the trait, they don't use `this.type`, are pretty complicated on the whole, and I don't actually see what you're gaining by avoiding the supertype here.

Comment: @Astrid There is many cases where you need to handle the subclasses instead of the superclass.

Comment: @Astrid hm, you are right. Actually I had in mind all the features subclass has but I cannot access them from the superclass method anyway. Thanks! How lame I am...

Comment: @Astrid No, it can't. I tried it, but then type T doesn't match

Comment: No, `(new MyClass(d)).asInstanceOf[this.type]` is a bad idea. The usage of `asInstanceOf` should be reserved for the situations where you are sure that you know what the right type is, but it cannot be proved through static type checking. The `asInstanceOf` is there to promise *true* things, not to make obviously wrong statements. `(new MyClass(d)).asInstanceOf[this.type]` is guaranteed to be wrong. Please refrain from using `asInstanceOf` in this way.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, it is obviously wrong, but it works! So it's like a cheat. I just wander what may go wrong? So one instance of a class is seen as another instance of the same class. So what exactly is dangerous there? (just notice, my code doesn't control a power-plant)

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov The problem with this code is not that you might blow up a power-plant. The problem with this code is that if someone sees it in a code review, your boss might never allow you to write critical code for a power plant in the first place ;) Anyway, I've updated my answer with an example that produces a ClassCastException.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Haha I agree with you, luckily I'm just an end user, no crucial code for me for sure. Anyway I didn't succeed to implement your code (probably some scala release mismatch), so I'll stay with my ugly, until all crashes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this.type` is the [singleton type](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types) that is inhabited by one single value, namely `this`. Therefore, accepting a function of type `f: X => this.type` as an argument is guaranteed to be nonsensical, because every invocation of `f` can just be replaced by `this` (plus the side-effects performed by `f`).

Here is a way of forcing your code to compile with minimal changes:

```
trait Abst { self =>
  type T
  def met1(p: T) = p.toString
  def met2(p: T, f: Double => Abst { type T = self.T }){
    val v = f(1.0)
    v.met1(p)
  }
}

case class Param(a:Int)
class MyClass(x: Double) extends Abst {
  type T = Param
  val s = met2(Param(1), (d: Double) => new MyClass(d))
}
```

But honestly: don't do it. And also don't do any of the F-bounded-stuff either, it will probably end up as a total mess, especially if you are not familiar with the pattern. Instead, refactor your code so that you don't have any self-referential spirals in it.

---

**Update**

Remark on why telling to the compiler that `(new MyClass(d))` is of type `this.type` for some other `this: MyClass` is a really bad idea:

```
abstract class A {
  type T
  val x: T
  val f: T => Unit
  def blowup(a: A): Unit = a.asInstanceOf[this.type].f(x)
}

object A {
  def apply[X](point: X, function: X => Unit): A = new A {
    type T = X
    val x = point
    val f = function
  }
}

val a = A("hello", (s: String) => println(s.size))
val b = A(42, (n: Int) => println(n + 58))

b.blowup(a)
```

This blows up with a `ClassCastException`, despite `a` and `b` both being of type `A`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it required that Param is outside the MyClass scope? Maybe I can put it inside companion Object?

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov In the above code snippet, it is required, because otherwise every instance of `MyClass` would have its own `Param` type that is incompatible with any other `MyClass` params.  So, unless you want to make `MyClass` a singleton, it wouldn't make any sense to make `Param` inner class. If you decide to make it a singleton, then it's not quite clear what the `Abst` trait is good for in the first place. It's not quite clear how to "improve" it, because your original code looks like an XY-problem. Maybe you could add a paragraph or two on the motivation *why* you wrote this code?

Comment: Actually, once it was singleton, that's why Param is defined inside, but since now I have this constructor they are no more. Sorry for so less of the code I wanted to make it clear and simple, there are many many methods there, I thought I inserted all the relevant things. I added a few lines in my question, you may take a look please

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov Wait, what part of it doesn't work, specifically? I'm pretty sure that both snippets should compile, at least under 2.15 and upwards.

Comment: 2.11 here... It breaks on 'self' keyword already... but the rest is also suspicious

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this error message you have to use *[F-bounded polymorphism](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html)*.

Your code will look somewhat like this:

```
trait Abst[F <: Abst[F, T], T]{ self: F =>

  def met1(p: T): String = p.toString

  def met2(p: T, f: Double => F): String = {
    val v = f(1.0)
    v.met1(p)
  }
}

case class Param(a:Int)

class MyClass(x: Double) extends Abst[MyClass, Param] {
  val s = met2(Param(1), (d: Double) => new MyClass(d))
}
```

### Explanation:

Using `self: F =>` inside of a trait or class definition constraints the value of `this`. So your code will not compile if `this` is not of type `F`.

We are using a cyclic type constraint of `F`: `F <: Abst[F, T]`. Though counterintuitive, the compiler does not mind it.

In the implementation, `MyClass`, we then extend `MyClass` with `Abst[MyClass, Param]`, which in turn satisfies `F <: Abst[F, T]`.

Now you can use `F` as return type of a function in `Abst` and have the `MyClass` return `MyClass` in the implementation.

---

You might think this solution is ugly, and if you do, then you're right.

Instead of using *F-bounded polymorphism* it's always recommended to use **typeclasses for ad-hoc-polymorphism**.

You will find more information about it in the link I provided earlier.

Really, read it. It will change your view on generic programming forever.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reference, it is always good to see different approaches. And you are right, I think it's pretty ugly

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind making the trait take `T` as a generic parameter, this is a fairly simple and straightforward equivalent solution:

```
trait Abst[T]{
  def met1(p: T) = p.toString
  def met2(p: T, f: Double=>Abst[T]){
    val v = f(1.0)
    v.met1(p)
  }
}

case class Param(a:Int)
class MyClass(x: Double) extends Abst[Param]{
  val s = met2(Param(1), (d: Double) => new MyClass(d))
}
```

I say it's equivalent because you're not losing any information by having `met2` use the supertype instead of the subtype. The classic use case for referencing the subtype in a trait is e.g. having a method which you want to return `MyClass` instead of `Abst` even though it's defined in `Abst`, but that's not the situation you're in here. The only place your subtype reference is used is in the definition of `f`, and since function types are covariant on their output parameter you can pass any `f: Double => MyClass` into an `f: Double => Abst[T]` without problems.

If you do want to reference the subtype anyway, see Markus' answer... and if you do want to avoid having `T` be a generic parameter, things get a lot more complicated again, because now you have potential conflicts between the `T` of `Abst` versus the `T` of the subtype in the definition of `met2`.

Comment: You're right, this is the cleanest solution. Generally type T=Param is specific to each of MyClass classes and doesn't change. That's why it is inside the body and not generic

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov I see where you're coming from, but the problem with keeping `T` internal is that you have too much logic relying on it in `Abst`. The only way `met2` will work is if you have some way of saying "the function should create an `Abst` implementation where its `T` is the same as the `T` of `p`" - in other words, _precisely_ what generics do for you.